Restore-DbaDatabase - No backups passed through
I am relatively new to Powershell.
I am using bottom script to restore database.
Set-DbatoolsInsecureConnection -SessionOnly

Get-ChildItem "C:\NH\WH_BEE_$(Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd")_*.bak" | `
Restore-DbaDatabase `
    -SqlInstance "Bee\BEESQL2022" `
    -DatabaseName "WH_BEE" `
    -FileMapping @{
       "WH_Data1" = "C:\WH_BEE.MDF";
       "WH_Data2" = "C:\WH_BEE.NDF";
       "WH_Log" = "C:\WH_BEE.LDF"
    };

This is related to my previous post which I did not get it resolved.
When I ran this, I got bottom error message:
WARNING: [23:48:28][Restore-DbaDatabase] No backups passed through. 
 This could mean the SQL instance cannot see the referenced files, the file's headers 
could not be read or some other issue

Module: sql


FullName                 Value Description                 
--------                 ----- -----------                 
sql.connection.trustcert True  Trust SQL Server certificate
sql.connection.encrypt   False Encrypt connection to server

As far as permission is concerned, I added "SQL Server Agent Account" and "Everyone" full permission to this folder and drive.
